# Mobile - product listings page - add to basket button or not?

Tags: e-commerce, mobile-web

So on our site we currently have something like:

- DURACELL BATTERY - ONLY £1.99 - QUANTITY - ADD TO BASKET
- ENERGIZER BATTERY - ONLY £1.99 - QUANTITY - ADD TO BASKET

Obviously in designing our mobile site I am thinking is this the best use of space on our mobile version of the site, HOWEVER I have the trade off that I also know this is our most used button on the desktop version of the site.

I am also aware that the journey on a mobile is different and the user wouldn't necessarily be expecting to add to basket at that early stage of their journey.

I am leaning towards the common practice (looking through various large e-commerce sites):

- DURACELL BATTERY - ONLY £1.99 >

And so on...

Comment: So in the second option, the link takes you to a full page with more info and the add to basket link for the item, right?

Comment: I'm not into marketing but I really hate the word "only" or "just" next to a price.

Comment: @ Jim - Yes, that's the plan with the second option. However I managed to get our CSS to play nicely with the add to basket button so now I have the luxury that when we launch the mobile we can actually A/B Test the both of them.

@Ben - I really hadn't thought about that, it will be worth us doing some A/B Testing on that too! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your business and users. Displaying Add to cart button may make sense for online grocery system, but user would want to see more details or specification in case of electronic items or fashion items. Personally i would prefer add to card button on detail page, you can add more details in the list.

[image]

Comment: That's not too far from what I've got - as mentioned above, now I've managed to fit it on the page I am probably going to have a go at A/B testing and comparing checkouts.

![Screengrab](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/CnWlogG02XKJh2U_s0GCjdqcqX0Jk56XczmFsC_1lTpz77RdpiZs_8j7qjR_aLC7D4mGcCcAAwc)

Comment: Do you have many repeat customers? Are they ordering the same item(s) with each order? 

In my experience, users on mobile will commit to the same tasks as they would on desktop - with a certain level of immediacy. If they're searching your site on mobile, does it stand to reason that they'd want to purchase immediately and having an extra click would be an impediment to that task?

You could always run an AB on having the "add to basket" button on the listing and see which converts more or a smaller cart abandonment rate.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on how users purchasing items in desktop. Do they purchase single item or Multiple items in average?

If users are buying multiple items together, I recommend to add an Icon on the right side as its a famous battery(In this case), they don't need to check the description or reviews everytime.

If users are buying only single item in average, you don't have to put the button on the list.